# Error foreign key when doing migration Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5.8

I have an error on Laravel 5.8

I am getting error on foreign key constraints. Here's my Schema..

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok, first of all, why 2 function up() ? Also, you don't need `subcategories` as a different table, because you would have parent_id as an extra column in categories table itself.

Comment: these `up()` functions are in two files right?

Comment: what exact error you are getting? what's the order of your migration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating `categories` table after `subcategories`. Time `subcategory` table gets created, there are notable called `categories`. So it throws an error.

To handle this you can do two things

1. Create the `categories` table before `subcategories` table. ([master-slave table / parent-child table](https://www.calebcurry.com/parent-child-tables/))
2. create a separate migration file for foreign key update. Create a new file and just add below foreign key like below

   `$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put `Categories` Table up and `sub categories` below it. Because when you run this command it tries to create subcategory first which requires Category Id which is not yet existed.

Answer (score 0):

Referenced key must have similar data types.Please check your table with data types for the foreign key column. The size and sign of integer types must be the same.